Dropdown Menu For Images P5js
I am trying to make a drop down menu in p5js that displays images. I keep running into an error with loading images. When I attempted to troubleshoot and loaded an image in another sketch I did not get the error but I am getting it here. I am hoping a fresh pair of eyes could help. Thank you for your time and help!
let picker; 
let drum1, drum2, drum3, drum4, drum5;
let img;
let drumType = 'what';

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

    drum1 = loadImage('drum1.jgp');
    drum2 = loadImage('drum2.jpg');
    drum3 = loadImage('drum3.jpg');
    drum4 = loadImage('drum4.jpg');
    drum5 = loadImage('drum5.jpg');

    textAlign(CENTER);
    background(200);
  
    picker = createSelect();
 
    picker.position(10, 10);

    picker.option('djembe');
    picker.option('two hand drums');
    picker.option('one hand drum');
    picker.option('Talking drum');
    picker.option('five hand drums');
   
    picker.changed(pickEvent);

    img = drum5;
}

function draw() {
    background(200, 220, 10);
    textAlign(LEFT);
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    text(trim + ' is a good drum', 10, 50); // look up what trim is

}

function pickEvent() {
    // get the item chosen with .value()
    drumType = picker.value();
        
    if (drumType === 'djembe') {
        img = drum1;
    } else if (drumType === 'two hand drum') {
        img = drum2;
    } else if (drumType === 'one hand drum') {
        img = drum3;
    } else if (drumType === 'talking drum'){
        img = drum4;
    } else  {
        img = drum5;
    }

}





What error are you getting, specifically? Errors are good--they usually tell you exactly where and what the problem is, which is usually 80% of debugging. Probable typo: drum1.jgp. Where was trim defined?

There are many issues with your code. Remarks:

Code slowly and run your code often, verifying each step. If you blaze ahead and write complex code without testing each step along the way, you'll accrue a bunch of errors and it'll be confusing to try to resolve them all at once. It's much harder to untangle a large ball of yarn than a small one.
Breaking large problems into smaller pieces helps with this--instead of trying to get 5 images working, just get one loaded, then two, then many.

Always provide all errors in full. Errors are good. They tell you exactly where and what the problem is. The programs that are toughest to debug have no errors and silently misbehave.

If your images aren't loading, make sure you're hosting them on a development server.

All variables must be defined before you can use them. trim was never defined in your code, so that'll crash the program.

Whenever you're doing thing1, thing2, ... thing5 or a long series of if-else ifs, use data structures and iteration: arrays, objects and loops. thing1, thing2 isn't scalable--what if you have 100 or 50 million of the thing? The code would explode. Loops, arrays and objects automatically handle dynamic numbers of items without having to hardcode anything.

If you're loading images, usually do it in the preload function so they're ready to go by the time your app runs.

Separate data and logic to keep the application flexible. The array of objects here is raw data that could come from a server or file.

Scope variables locally. Don't make them global unless you absolutely have to. let drumType = 'what'; can be scoped locally to pickEvent, which should be given an action name since it's a function: handlePick or similar.


Here's a cleaned up version:


// TODO: add your own images; these are samples
const images = [
  {
    name: "djembe",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/100",
  },
  {
    name: "two hand drums",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/2/100",
  },
  {
    name: "one hand drum",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/3/100",
  },
  {
    name: "talking drum",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/4/100",
  },
  {
    name: "five hand drums",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/5/100",
  },
];
let selectedImage = images[0];
let select;

function preload() {
  for (const e of images) {
    e.image = loadImage(e.url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  select = createSelect();
  select.position(10, 10);
  select.changed(handleSelected);
  images.forEach(e => select.option(e.name));
}

function draw() {
  background(200, 220, 10);
  image(selectedImage.image, 0, 30, 100, 100);
  text(`${selectedImage.name} is a good drum`, 120, 50);
}

function handleSelected() {
  selectedImage = images.find(e => e.name === select.value());
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.10.0/p5.js"></script>



Note that there's potential room for improvement: the image and text are totally static, so you don't need draw() running at 60 FPS. You can redraw only when the dropdown changes and save energy/batteries/CPU work for the client:


const images = [
  {
    name: "djembe",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/100",
  },
  {
    name: "two hand drums",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/2/100",
  },
  {
    name: "one hand drum",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/3/100",
  },
  {
    name: "talking drum",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/4/100",
  },
  {
    name: "five hand drums",
    url: "https://picsum.photos/id/5/100",
  },
];
let selectedImage = images[0];
let select;

function preload() {
  for (const e of images) {
    e.image = loadImage(e.url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  select = createSelect();
  select.position(10, 10);
  select.changed(handleSelected);
  images.forEach(e => select.option(e.name));
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(200, 220, 10);
  image(selectedImage.image, 0, 30, 100, 100);
  text(`${selectedImage.name} is a good drum`, 120, 50);
}

function handleSelected() {
  selectedImage = images.find(e => e.name === select.value());
  draw();
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.10.0/p5.js"></script>



